# Assistance changing a div to another div using J-query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello creating a receipe book on my website, trying to change the content of a Div using J-Query.

Essentially what I want is to have a next and previous button which scroll through receipe1,receipe2 and receipe3 and they're respective receipe-img1, 2 and 3. Whilst also showing/hiding the previous one

Had some help from the guys below, but not quite there yet

```
      <div class="receipe1">
                <h1>Old Fashioned</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
      <div class="receipe2">
                <h1>Test Receipe2</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
      <div class="receipe3">
                <h1>Test Receipe3</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>

      .receipe2,
      .receipe-img2,
      .receipe3,
      .receipe-img3 {
      display: none;
      }

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#changeText").click(function() {
            $(".receipe2").css("display", "block");
            $(".receipe-img2").css("display", "block");
            $(".receipe1").appendTo('.receipe2');
            $(".receipe1").css("display", "none");
            $(".receipe-img1").appendTo('.receipe-img2');
           });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: pls show your HTML also

Comment: `$('receipe2')` means you are looking for the tag `receipe2` (so you have `<receipe2>...</receipe2>` in your html). Is this the case?

Comment: @Dekel is right it should be $(".receipe2") if you are looking for class not tag.

Comment: `$(".receipe1") $("receipe2")` this is not right. And `$("receipe2")` should be `$(".receipe2")`

Comment: Sorry heres my html css

Comment: @GillesC, you can't know this without looking at the HTML.

Comment: what do you mean by **change receipe1 to receipe2**

Comment: @Dekel I like to assume people write valid HTML and I'm pretty sure  `receipe2` is not a valid HTML tag. Plus the rest of the code `.appendTo('.receipe2')` kind of indicate it was a typo.

Comment: seems like the OP , by  saying `change receipe1 to receipe2 ` meant , adding the content from `.receipe1` inside the `receipe2` ? i don't really understand what he wants to achieve

Comment: Edited original post to me more specific sorry

Comment: @SamDucker Updated my answer below. check it out and let me know if that's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeText").click(function() {
        $(".receipe2").css("display", "block");
        $(".receipe1").appendTo('.receipe2');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added an extra line and it worked a treat. 


        '  $(".receipe1").css("display", "none"); '

Comment: One last question if instead of just changing the div I wanted to have a next and previous buttons which scroll between  receipe1, receipe2, receipe3 what would be the best way to achieve that instead?

Answer (score 0):

New answer ( hope i understood right what you want )

Keep in mind that you can change the little things like how you hide/show the `.receipe`s , how you position them etc.

I made the below example ( it works with any number of reciepes )

let me know if it helps

```js
 var nrreceipe = $(".receipe").length;
 i = 1
    $("button").click(function() {
        var hideme =   $(this).siblings("#receipe_wrap").children(".receipe").filter(":visible")
           
   if (i < nrreceipe) { 
  
         if ( $(this).is("#Next")) {
    
             $(hideme).hide().animate({left:'-100%'},350);
              var showme = $(hideme).nextAll(".receipe").filter(":hidden").eq(0)
              $(showme).show().animate({left:'0%'},350);
              
         i++
         }
    }
   if ( i>1 ){
        if ( $(this).is("#Previous")) {
         
             $(hideme).hide().animate({left:'-100%'},350);
              var showme = $(hideme).prevAll(".receipe").filter(":hidden").eq(0)
              $(showme).show().animate({left:'0%'},350);
              i--
         
         }
   }
 });
```

```css
.receipe:not(:first-child){
display:none;
left:-100%;
}
.receipe {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:0px;
  padding:0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="receipe_wrap">


<div class="receipe1 receipe">
                <h1>Old Fashioned</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
      <div class="receipe2 receipe">
                <h1>Test Receipe2</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
      <div class="receipe3 receipe">
                <h1>Test Receipe3</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
      <div class="receipe4 receipe">
                <h1>Test Receipe4</h1>
                <h4><u>ingredients</u></h4>
                <h2>Serves 1</h2>
                <p>A generous shot of Kentucky straight bourbon<br>
                One shot of rye whiskey preferably Rittenhouse <br>
                Sugar cubes to your taste<br>
                Angostura bitters<br>
                <u>Garnish:</u> Orange twst<br>
      </div>
 </div>
   <button id="Previous">Previous</button>
  <button id="Next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Hey I just used, Dan's solution above what is the difference between the two different methods. One last question if instead of just changing the div I wanted to have a next and previous buttons which scroll between  receipe1, receipe2, receipe3

Comment: my solution is different because it changes the content of the `.receipe1` with the content of `.receipe2` . Dan's solution appends the whole div `.receipe1` inside the `.receipe2` div . ( if you look at the resulting html you will see the difference ) . plus..as i you can see in my solution the text from `receipe1` doesn't exist anymore. Please be more specific about what you want and what result you want to have

Comment: Edited my answer with another solution. let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: I think I'm nearly there with you now, I understand what you are doing with the code, and it makes sense. But I think they're is some sort of silly error on my part. So I've copied out the exact code you posted, but it functions on this snippet here but doesnt function on my version. Do I need to include the js into a seperate document? Or just using <script></script> at the bottom of the page as usual.

Comment: you need to include the script before `</body>` and also don't forget to include jQuery inside `<head>` ( also check in console and tell me if there's an error/message etc. )

Comment: So I can get a test example to work, I've made a codepen at http://codepen.io/samducker/pen/dORWrJ to show you what I'm working with. The receipe img also needs to change aswell as the text.

Comment: well. as you could see in my example...the buttons are siblings with the div that wraps around the receipes. so you need to change that line in JQ because in your code, they are not siblings, the HTML structures differs from your code to mine

see jsfiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/oxth1s07/  . for the img to work the is still some work to be done. BUT i answered your original question more than enought.  you should be able to continue on your own.